# Sorting a List of Maps dynamically in Ascending and Descending order

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I am having `Map`s inside a `List`.

I need to sort the `List` based on the input dynamically by passing it as a parameter into the method `sortData`.

It is working as expected, but the problem is that am not able to sort the list in ***reverse order***.

I'm getting an Error : `The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object`

*Code*

```
public class TestingClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List< LinkedHashMap<String,Object> > list = new ArrayList<>(); 
        
        /*Map 2*/
        LinkedHashMap<String,Object> lhm1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        lhm1.put("LONG_HEADER", 2l);
        lhm1.put("STRING_HEADER1", "C");
        lhm1.put("STRING_HEADER2", "D");

        /*Map 2*/

        LinkedHashMap<String,Object> lhm2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        lhm2.put("LONG_HEADER", 1l);
        lhm2.put("STRING_HEADER1", "E");
        lhm2.put("STRING_HEADER2", "F");
        
        /*Map 3*/       
        LinkedHashMap<String,Object> lhm3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        lhm3.put("LONG_HEADER", 3l);
        lhm3.put("STRING_HEADER1", "A");
        lhm3.put("STRING_HEADER2", "B");
        
        list.add(lhm1);
        list.add(lhm2);
        list.add(lhm3);
        
        List< LinkedHashMap<String,Object> > sortedList1 = sortData(list,"LONG_HEADER","ASC" );
        System.out.println("Output 1 After sorting" +sortedList1);
        List< LinkedHashMap<String,Object> > sortedList2 = sortData(list,"STRING_HEADER1","ASC" );
        System.out.println("Output 2 After sorting"+sortedList2);
        List< LinkedHashMap<String,Object> > sortedList3 = sortData(list,"STRING_HEADER2","ASC" );
        System.out.println("Output 3 After sorting"+sortedList3);
        
        /* It won't work */
        sortData(list,"LONG_HEADER","DESC" );
        sortData(list,"STRING_HEADER1","DESC" );
        sortData(list,"STRING_HEADER2","DESC" );
    }

    private static List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> sortData(List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> inputGridData,
            String sortBy, String sortOrder) {
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> lOutputGridDat = null;
        if (inputGridData.get(0).get(sortBy) instanceof Long) {
            if( "ASC".equals(sortOrder)) {
                lOutputGridDat = inputGridData.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(o -> ((Long) o.get(sortBy))))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            else {
                /*Here am getting error  if i use .reversed() method*/
                //Error : The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object
                lOutputGridDat = inputGridData.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(o -> ((Long) o.get(sortBy))).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

        } else {
            if( "ASC".equals(sortOrder)) {
                lOutputGridDat = inputGridData.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> ((String) o.get(sortBy))))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            else {
                /*Here am getting error  if i use .reversed() method*/
                // Error : The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object
                lOutputGridDat = inputGridData.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> ((String) o.get(sortBy))).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
        return lOutputGridDat;
    }   
}
```

**Map 1** After sorting

```
[{LONG_HEADER=1, STRING_HEADER1=E, STRING_HEADER2=F}, {LONG_HEADER=2, STRING_HEADER1=C, STRING_HEADER2=D}, {LONG_HEADER=3, STRING_HEADER1=A, STRING_HEADER2=B}]
```

**Map 2** After sorting

```
[{LONG_HEADER=3, STRING_HEADER1=A, STRING_HEADER2=B}, {LONG_HEADER=2, STRING_HEADER1=C, STRING_HEADER2=D}, {LONG_HEADER=1, STRING_HEADER1=E, STRING_HEADER2=F}]
```

**Map 3** After sorting

```
[{LONG_HEADER=3, STRING_HEADER1=A, STRING_HEADER2=B}, {LONG_HEADER=2, STRING_HEADER1=C, STRING_HEADER2=D}, {LONG_HEADER=1, STRING_HEADER1=E, STRING_HEADER2=F}]
```

Comment: What's exactly the error you're getting.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko am using object because the map value map contain String or Integer or any datatype.

Comment: @AlfredoTostón
I have slightly edited my question,
the issue is am not able to reverse the sorted list 
I have commented like below
//Error : The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko , Yes thanks it is working for String, not for Long data type, so am just sorting in Ascending order then am Using ` Collections.reverse(lOutputGridDat);` for descending order

Comment: @Pravinkumar For `Long` it should be `Comparator.<Map<String, Object>, Long>comparing(o -> ((Long) etc... )` I hope you've understood the principle of how the **comparator** should be written in case you are chaining the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth to point out at some **important issues** with the code you've provided :

- As I've said, it's **not a good** practice to use `Object` as generic type. Generics were introduced to enforce the type safety, using `Object` as generic type is as bad as don't use generics at all.
- Don't store the elements of different types together in a single collection. And avoid `instanceof` checks and type casting.
- Don't write your code against concrete classes like `LinkedHashMap` - variable type has to be `Map` instead.

*You can find more elaborate explanation on all account mentioned above on this site if you doubt if these suggestions have a value.*

With regard to your question, ***comparators*** as defined in your'r code will not compile.

That's you can fix it:

```
Comparator.<Map<String, Object>, String>comparing(
                o -> ((String) o.get(sortBy))).reversed()
```

When you're chaining the methods, the compiler is unable to infer the type of the prameter `o` inside the `comparing` based on the type of the elements of the stream.

Parameter `o` is treated not as a `Map` but as `Object` therefore you can't invoke `get()` on it.

Generic type information needs to be provided explicitly: `<Map<String, Object>, String>`. Where the *first part* - type of the argument passed into `comparing` (i.e. element of the stream), the second is a type of value that will be used for comparison (i.e. string).

[*for information on the syntax of generic methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)